# Is there a PL/SQL function to count the number of n subtypes of a super type?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, subtype

Is there a function in PL/SQL that can count the number of n subtypes of a table (supertype)?

I've tried the following:

```
select
    count(distinct value(t1))
from table t1;

select
    count(distinct treat(value(t1))
from table t1;
```

Basically, if a table has 6 subtypes, I would like a query that could output 6.

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected output would be helpful

Comment: What is a "subtype" and a "supertype"? These are not technical terms in Oracle db. By the way, do you really mean PL/SQL function, or do you mean Oracle SQL? (A lot of people have no clue what PL/SQL means - they just assume, incorrectly, that that's the name of the Oracle dialect of SQL.)

Comment: @mathguy `SUBTYPE` is a [keyword in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99934) and is a technical term. In this case (given the OP's use of `VALUE()` and `TREAT()`) they are talking about [Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i7504) and inheritance of those types using the `UNDER` keyword to define a supertype with inherited subtypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TYPE parent_type AS OBJECT( id NUMBER ) NOT FINAL;
CREATE TYPE child1_type UNDER parent_type ( c1 NUMBER );
CREATE TYPE child2_type UNDER parent_type ( c2 NUMBER ) NOT FINAL;
CREATE TYPE child3_type UNDER child2_type ( c3 NUMBER );

CREATE TABLE test_data ( value parent_type );

INSERT INTO test_data ( value )
  SELECT parent_type( 1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child1_type( 2, 1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child1_type( 3, 1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child1_type( 4, 1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child2_type( 5, 2 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child2_type( 6, 2 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child3_type( 7, 3, 1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child3_type( 8, 3, 1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child3_type( 9, 3, 1 ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If you know the type hierarchy then you can build a query manually using the fact that `TREAT( object AS type )` will return `NULL` if the object you are passing is not of that type and can use a `CASE` statement and start from the leaves of the hierarchy tree and process the types from deepest inheritance depth through to the parent type:

```sql
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT
         CASE
         WHEN TREAT( value AS child3_type ) IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'child3_type' -- deepest subtype
         WHEN TREAT( value AS child2_type ) IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'child2_type' -- supertype of child3_type, subtype of parent_type
         WHEN TREAT( value AS child1_type ) IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'child1_type' -- subtype of parent_type
         ELSE 'parent_type'
         END
       ) AS num_types
FROM   test_data
```

**Query 2**:

If you have access to the [`SYS.ANYDATA` type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_anydat.htm#ARPLS077) then you can [get the type of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045527/1509264):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(
         DISTINCT
         SYS.ANYDATA.getTypeName(
           SYS.ANYDATA.convertObject( value )
         )
       ) AS num_types
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

Both give the same output:

> ```
> | NUM_TYPES |
> | --------: |
> |         4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ac02038ec0fac646d81da3858c09146f)*