# Oracle Object Relational Database inserting records into a table with reference to a derived table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following structure below and I want to add a record into `project` table. The problem with the following INSERT is that on the place of `customer_t` I have to select a record from `user` table while inserting but I want to select only customers (and not staff members). Basically `customer_t` and `staff_t` inherit from `user_t` (table: user).

You can look at same insert but for service_t, it works fine because I'm selecting from a table, but in this case, there is no table for customer.

I'm not so experience with this ORM. Any idea how to solve it?

```
INSERT INTO project VALUES (
  1,
  'Project name',
  'Description',
  ( SELECT REF(u) AS customer_t
    FROM   "USER" u
    WHERE  idno = 1
    AND    VALUE(u) IS OF TYPE (customer_t)
  ),
  ( SELECT REF(s) FROM service s WHERE serviceno = 1)
);
```

Error message:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO project VALUES (1, 'Project name', 'Logo', (SELECT REF(u) AS customer_t FROM "USER" u WHERE idno = 1 AND VALUE(u) IS OF TYPE (customer_t)), (SELECT REF(s) FROM service s WHERE serviceno = 1))
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 72
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF C##EX_TEST.CUSTOMER_T got REF C##EX_TEST.USER_T
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

SQL:

```sql
CREATE TYPE name_t AS OBJECT (
  first_name     VARCHAR2(32),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(32)
);

CREATE TYPE address_t AS OBJECT (
  province       VARCHAR2(32),
  street         VARCHAR2(32),
  city           VARCHAR2(32),
  postal_code    VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TYPE user_t AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
  email          VARCHAR2(40),
  password       VARCHAR2(32),
  name           name_t,
  address        address_t,
  phone          VARCHAR2(15),
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE rank_t AS OBJECT (
  rankno       NUMBER,
  name         VARCHAR2(40),
  description  VARCHAR2(60)
);

CREATE TABLE "RANK" OF rank_t (
  PRIMARY KEY (rankno),
  UNIQUE (name)
);

INSERT INTO "RANK" VALUES (1, 'User', 'Simple a user');
INSERT INTO "RANK" VALUES (2, 'Manager', 'Manager');
INSERT INTO "RANK" VALUES (3, 'Administrator', 'Admin');

CREATE TYPE customer_t UNDER user_t (

);

CREATE TYPE staff_t UNDER user_t (
  salary       NUMBER(7,2),
  rank         REF rank_t
);

CREATE TABLE "USER" OF user_t (
  PRIMARY KEY (idno),
  UNIQUE (email));

CREATE TYPE service_t AS OBJECT (
  serviceno    NUMBER,
  name         VARCHAR2(40),
  description  VARCHAR2(60)
);

CREATE TABLE service OF service_t (PRIMARY KEY (serviceno));

CREATE TYPE project_t AS OBJECT (
  projectno    NUMBER,
  name         VARCHAR2(40),
  description  VARCHAR2(60),
  customer     REF customer_t,
  service      REF service_t
);

CREATE TABLE project OF project_t (PRIMARY KEY (projectno));
```

Comment: You created `TYPE customer_t` but no `TABLE` of that type. You have nothing to ref at `TABLE project.customer` .

Comment: @Serg Of course you do, the `USER` object table stores `user_t` types and `customer_t` (and `staff_t`) is a sub-type of that object and can be stored in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate table for a customers; just insert the types into the `USER` table.

If you want to put a customer in then insert a `customer_t` type:

```sql
INSERT INTO "USER" VALUES(
  customer_t(
    1,
    'person1@customer.example.com',
    'abcdefg',
    name_t( 'One', 'Uno' ),
    address_t( 'province','street', 'city', '12345' ),
    '0123456789'
  )
);
```

If you want to insert a user then use `user_t` or insert values without a type:

```sql
INSERT INTO "USER" VALUES(
    2,
    'person2@user.example.com',
    'abcdefg',
    name_t( 'Two', 'Dos' ),
    address_t( 'province','street', 'city', '12345' ),
    '0123456789'
);
```

If you want to insert a staff member then use `staff_t`:

```sql
INSERT INTO "USER" VALUES(
  staff_t(
    3,
    'person3@staff.example.com',
    'abcdefg',
    name_t( 'Three', 'Tres' ),
    address_t( 'province','street', 'city', '12345' ),
    '0123456789',
    12345.67,
    (SELECT REF(r) FROM "RANK" r WHERE rankno = 2 )
  )
);
```

Then the data will have the correct types (which you [can extract using `SYS.ANYDATA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58196805/1509264)) and use the `TREAT` function to convert a super-type to a sub-type:

```sql
SELECT idno,
       email,
       SYS.ANYDATA.getTypeName( SYS.ANYDATA.convertObject( VALUE(u) ) ) As type,
       TREAT(VALUE(u) AS staff_t).salary AS salary,
       TREAT(VALUE(u) AS staff_t).rank.name AS rank
FROM   "USER" u
```

outputs:

> ```
> IDNO | EMAIL                        | TYPE                                   |   SALARY | RANK   
> ---: | :--------------------------- | :------------------------------------- | -------: | :------
>    1 | person1@customer.example.com | FIDDLE_KPHUNVHPVRKOYQBWVAQS.CUSTOMER_T |     null | null   
>    2 | person2@user.example.com     | FIDDLE_KPHUNVHPVRKOYQBWVAQS.USER_T     |     null | null   
>    3 | person3@staff.example.com    | FIDDLE_KPHUNVHPVRKOYQBWVAQS.STAFF_T    | 12345.67 | Manager
> ```

and:

```sql
SELECT idno,
       email
FROM   "USER" u
WHERE  VALUE(u) IS OF TYPE (customer_t)
```

outputs:

> ```
> IDNO | EMAIL                       
> ---: | :---------------------------
>    1 | person1@customer.example.com
> ```

and your insert needs to convert the `REF` from the `user_t` super-type to the `customer_t` sub-type using the [`TREAT` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions198.htm):

```sql
INSERT INTO project VALUES (
  1,
  'Project name',
  'Description',
  ( SELECT TREAT( REF(u) AS REF customer_t )
    FROM   "USER" u
    WHERE  idno = 1
    AND    VALUE(u) IS OF TYPE (customer_t)
  ),
  ( SELECT REF(s) FROM service s WHERE serviceno = 1)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=18a4b0cac4bc8bec005e68b9df2f6afa)*